# Predicting next destination in the sequence. What type of classification it is?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, recommendation-engine, sequences, multiclass-classification

How to decide what modelling to use?

Comment: Unfortunately this site's format doesn't work well with this kind of question: please add code you've written and approaches you've tried and then ask about a *specific problem* you are having.

Comment: @MBack This question is now effectively useless because you removed the vital parts of your original question. Please either add back the information you removed or delete this question.

Comment: @not_a_robot Yes I wanted to delete..but cant as it is answered now

Answer (score 0):

You're right - this isn't a regression problem, unless there's some linear logic behind each of your hotel's label (e.g. hotel 65 is 65 miles away, while hotel 66 is 66 miles away). That doesn't seem to be the case, but if it were, then it's a simple regression problem in which you'd basically predict how far an individual is going to get their hotel. However, I disgress.

#### What you really ought to look into is [Multiclass classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification), as you've indicated.

If you have any experience with [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html), performing this type of analysis [should not be difficult](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html); check out the [`OneVsRestClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier). There's even a great [tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_multilabel.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-multilabel-py) out there on how to use that specific class.

Comment: not_a_robot   Thanks a lot for the suggestions and links. I was thinking in the same direction. Yes i have some experience working with scikit-learn. So user_id, hotel_id , continent_id are categorical variables. If I convert them into binary, then I will get too many new features and very sparse. Can you suggest some better way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### recommender systems

try to predict what 'product' a user will buy next.